# Transfer data from Normal Map to another with a different UV Map

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

I have a model in blender uv unwarped and have a normal map, now I have created a new different uv for the model, so the old normal map is no longer working, how can I transfer data from the old normal map to anew one based on the new uv map.

Comment: You could bake again from your high-poly, or you could bake the normal from the first version of your object to the version that has the new UV, for your first object directly plug the normal into the Output and bake the Emit